# I want to convert 0-5 volt to 4 to 20 mA current loop through a self powered load

Tags: constant-current

I have done this circuit diagram in Multisim where the R1 is the variable voltage source and the load is represented by the black box. There are two problems:

1. If I change the load resistance the output current changes.
2. If I use 9V to 5V converter the output current is beyond my control.

[image]

Comment: I would be careful using Multisim. It's a great tool, sure, but there are parameters from semiconductors that the software doesn't recognize. Multisim is more for academic purposes and it should be avoided for professional use.

Comment: Then please suggest me some professional simulation software

Comment: I do recommend LTSpice, it's free and open source and it updates occasionally. It'll take some time for you to learn the software because it's very different. It took me about a week to learn how to do a simple DC sweep simulation LOL. Multisim is still really good but for calculating things for semiconductors, it tends to ignore parameters (e.g. for a MOSFET, it ignores any drain to body leakage capacitance, for one example). People also use PSpice but that software is _way_ out of date and I think they discontinued its lifetime development.

Answer (score 2):

The LM7809 draws way too much current for this application (typical 5mA, maximum 8mA)- you have maybe 3.6mA to work with for your **entire circuit** (4mA worst case, but you should allow output current to go a bit under 4mA).

The second problem is that you are not measuring the current thorough the GND pin so it is an additional current to your current sink. You are also not measuring the current through R3 or Q2.  You need a different circuit to do this that measuring all the current drawn by the circuit. Typically one would add a resistor in series with the negative (or positive) input lead.